# keep a div active after selecting it using ajax jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using ajax to to show data from data base.
Basically it's a chat app, and when user clicks on certain conversation it appends the data to a view.

My conversation div is:

```html
<div class="kt-widget__item">
  <span class="kt-media kt-media--circle">
      <img src="{{ asset('media/users/100_4.jpg') }}" alt="image">
  </span>
  <div class="kt-widget__info">
    <div class="kt-widget__section">
      <a href="#" class="kt-widget__username">Teresa Fox</a>
    </div>
    <span class="kt-widget__desc">
      PR Executive
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="kt-widget__action">
    <span class="kt-widget__date">4 Days</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

and a demo CSS for this div is:

```
   .kt-widget__item {
        cursor: pointer;
        background: darkgrey;
        border-radius: 8px;
        font-size: 15px;
        color: black;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100%;a
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
}
    .kt-widget__item:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
        border-radius: 10px;
        border: 1px solid darkgrey;
        background:  rgb(187, 184, 184);
        font-size: 15px;
        color: black;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100%;
        margin: auto;
}
    .kt-widget__item:active {
        border-radius: 10px;
        border: 1px solid rgb(156, 155, 155);
        background: rgb(156, 155, 155);
        
}
```

Now I want to make the selected div active. How can this be done?

**Regards**
*Saad*

Answer (score 0):

**Important:** It is not possible to set the `:active` pseudo-class of an element with JavaScript. An element becomes active when a user activates it (typically with a mouse click), and becomes inactive when the user de-activates it (typically by un-clicking the mouse).

To ensure that a div looks like it is active, you should first set a `tabindex` attribute on the div, making it focusable.

Ref: [tabindex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex)

Then, to mimic the active appearance, add a `div:focus` CSS rule that exactly matches the `div:active` rule.

Finally, simply create the fake "active" appearance by calling `HTMLElement.focus()`.

Remove the fake "active" appearance by calling `HTMLElement.blur()`.

Example:

```js
const fdiv = document.getElementById('focusable');
const btn = document.getElementById("addfocus");
btn.onclick = function() {
  fdiv.focus();
};
const btn2 = document.getElementById("removefocus");
btn2.onclick = function() {
  fdiv.blur();
};
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 50%;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 12px 0;
}

div:active,
div:focus {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="not-focusable">I'm clickable but not focusable, click me</div>
<div id="focusable" tabindex="0">I'm focusable, click me</div>
<button id="addfocus">Focus the div</button>
<button id="removefocus">Blur the div</button><br/>
```

Comment: I can't understand this. brother can you please explain it a bit more..??

Comment: See my detailed explanation and working example, above. Please let me know if that answer makes sense to you.

Comment: Thanks Brother you made my day. Trying to figure it out since yesterday. finally succeeded.Thanks a lot.

Comment: You’re welcome. Do you accept the answer?